# Why does a Healer gain EXP then they don't kill an enemy

Tags: disgaea-2

Coming from Disgaea: Afternoon of Darkness and now playing Disgaea 2: Dark Hero Days i've been wondering for some time now, every time my healer uses one of her spells she seems to gain exp, on occasion she'll level up because of it yet when i get one of my other characters to just attack and enemy they only gain exp when they kill it

so why is my healer gaining exp when they don't even kill an enemy while everyone else only gains exp when they do?

Comment: Because it's made that way? I'm not really sure what your question is or what could be a valid answer to it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie In Disgaea a character gain's exp when they kill's an enemy, if they don't kill an enemy and only damage it, the don't gain anything, this means if 5 character gang up on a single enemy it's whoever who lands the final blow that gains the exp, with the healer, because her aptitudes for things like STR, DEF and HP are less than 100% she will gain less from equipping swords however since her aptitude for INT and SP are +100% she can gain more equipping staffs which have weak attack

Comment: @SevenSidedDie since healing and reinforcement spells can't kill it's strange how she's the only one gaining exp however even damaging the enemy, my question is asking why this happens, is it because of the staff type weapon or an innocent she may have on one of her armors or is it something unique to healers like how Mages have reduced SP cost for the same spells that Skull can learn

Comment: @SevenSidedDie i should point out that it's not impossible for a healer to kill, before i noticed this i was weakening enemies so she could land the final blow and if you grind alot you could make a healer into a master swordswoman cause you would either have her as a warrior then reincarnate to a healer with all her sword skills or grind up her sword skill as a healer (which would take a while because her sword affinity is low so it wont level up as quick)

Comment: Is this more of a reason of "why is the game designed this way?"  In that case, it's so healers don't HAVE to kill creatures and instead can focus on their function, allowing them to level up at a reasonable rate next to the other characters.  Your question is fairly unclear though, consider editing it.

Comment: @shatterspike1 i think i understand where i got my question wrong, i should have included that i came from playing Disgaea 1 and there's no documentation about "Healers gain EXP from using their spells to unlike other characters", edited that part in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand why, we need to examine what would happen if healers didn't gain exp from casting spells by looking at the original Disgaea. In the first game, this was not the case, which led to healers being a total pain to level up because you had to specially weaken an enemy and then have the healer kill it, or rely on the team attack system. This meant healers tended to lag behind in level significantly and required more work to be worthwhile. (healers were also under-powered compared to Flonne and Angels which made the issue even worse)

In later games in the series, including disgaea 2, healers gain EXP from healing to make them less awkward and annoying to level up. There isn't some in-universe justification offered or anything like that, its just a mechanic designed to prevent the process of leveling one from being frustrating

Comment: ok, i wasn't sure if it was the healers themselves or something that may have been equipped (an item or specialist in the item) to my healer that was causing it since i had just came from getting the good end of Disgaea 1 and did find that bloody annoying, now that i know it's not equipment i can go ahead and change her gear around